# How to retrieve id from previous inserted table key by Ecto Multi

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to retrieve id from previous inserted table primary key by Ecto Multi.

At first, I insert to A main table. then B details table needs A.id.
I tried following code.

```
Multi.new()
  |> Multi.insert(:insert, main)
  |> Multi.insert_all(:insert_all, B, details)
  |> Repo.transaction()
```

However I have no idea how to retrieve A.id for insert table B.
What I should do for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like the following example which creates a new `User` record and a new `Email` record (where the `email` record is associated to the parent `user` record via a `user_id` foreign key).

```
alias Ecto.Multi

user = get_user_params_from_form() # <-- or where-ever you are getting data
email = get_email_params_from_form()

Multi.new()
    |> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user))
    |> Multi.insert(
      :email,
      # Capture the id from the previous operation
      fn %{
           user: %User{
             id: user_id
           }
         } ->
        Email.changeset(%Email{user_id: user_id}, email)
      end
    )
```

I think this demonstrates the type of relationship you described.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Multi.merge](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#merge/2) to use the result of the first multi in a second multi.

This is the example from the docs:

```
multi =
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:post, %Post{title: "first"})

multi
|> Ecto.Multi.merge(fn %{post: post} ->
  # Here, post is the Post inserted in the first multi.
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:comment, Ecto.build_assoc(post, :comments))
end)
|> MyApp.Repo.transaction()
```

Update: I've added a comment about the `post` (your `A` model) that was created in the first multi. You can use `post.id` and assign it to the related comments (your `B` model).

Comment: either this or `Multi.run`

Comment: I cannot adapt to my insert_all code with my knowledge. Where can I get previous table id.

Comment: How can I get first inserted ID?