# How to insert main and detailed data at once by ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have main data and detailed data. I would like to insert both at one time.

```
-------
 main
-------
 id
 name
-------

---------
 detail
---------
 id
 main_id
 name
---------
```

I'm using Multi transaction by ecto. 
However I have no idea how to insert at once.

```
main = [name: "zaku"]
details = [%{main_id: 1, name: "hoge"}, %{main_id: 1, name: "moja"},]

Multi.new()
  |> Multi.insert(:main, Main.changeset(%Main{}, main))
  |> Multi.insert(:detail, Detail.changeset(%Detail{}, details))
  |> Repo.transaction()
```

The part in Detail insert does not work.
How can I do for it?

Answer (score 2):

The insert of the child does not work *because of transaction*. When the insertion of `Detail` is attempted, the parent does not yet exist.

One usually uses [`Ecto.build_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html?#build_assoc/3) to insert dependent records, or [**not recommended!**] you might get rid of the transaction and insert them one by one with two queries—this would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example here is similar to [the solution for your other example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61316039/274030), you just need to close the multiple queries with a call to the `transaction/1` function:

```
alias Ecto.Multi
alias Ecto.Repo

user = get_user_params_from_form() # <-- or where-ever you are getting data
email = get_email_params_from_form()

Multi.new()
    |> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user))
    |> Multi.insert(
      :email,
      # Capture the id from the previous operation
      fn %{
           user: %User{
             id: user_id
           }
         } ->
        Email.changeset(%Email{user_id: user_id}, email)
      end
    )
    |> Repo.transaction()
```

Personally, I don't find the `Multi` stuff very easy to work with, so sometimes I favor this other syntax, where you can pass a function to the [Repo.transaction/2 callback](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:transaction/2-use-with-function). Loosely, that looks something like this:

```
Repo.transaction(fn ->
  with {:ok, thing1} <- create_thing1(attrs1) do
    create_thing2(attrs2)
  else
    {:error, e} -> Repo.rollback(e)
  end
end)


def create_thing1(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %ThingOne{}
  |> ThingOne.changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end

def create_thing2(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %ThingTwo{}
  |> ThingTwo.changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```

It should be pointed out that this pattern can be used to wrap any task in a transaction.  E.g. if "thing2" is to interact with a 3rd party API, for example.